# echo vs <<<, or Useless Use of echo in Bash Award?

Tags: bash, io-redirection, pipe, performance

By now the [Useless Use of `cat` Award](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html) is very well known, and there's also a mention of a [Useless Use of `echo`](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#echo) (not relevant for this question). I'm wondering if there should be a "Useless Use of `echo` in Bash Award": Piping seems to be much slower than heredocs and herestrings according to some highly unscientific measurements:

- Heredocs:

  ```
  for reps in 1 2 3
  do
      time for i in {1..1000}
      do
          cat <<'END'
  test string
  END
      done > /dev/null
  done

  real    0m1.786s
  user    0m0.212s
  sys     0m0.332s

  real    0m1.817s
  user    0m0.232s
  sys     0m0.332s

  real    0m1.846s
  user    0m0.256s
  sys     0m0.320s
  ```
- Herestrings

  ```
  for reps in 1 2 3
  do
      time for i in {1..1000}
      do
          cat <<< 'test string'
      done > /dev/null
  done

  real    0m1.932s
  user    0m0.280s
  sys     0m0.288s

  real    0m1.956s
  user    0m0.248s
  sys     0m0.348s

  real    0m1.968s
  user    0m0.268s
  sys     0m0.324s
  ```
- Redirection

  ```
  for reps in 1 2 3
  do
      time for i in {1..1000}
      do
          echo 'test string' | cat
      done > /dev/null
  done

  real    0m3.562s
  user    0m0.416s
  sys     0m0.548s

  real    0m3.924s
  user    0m0.384s
  sys     0m0.604s

  real    0m3.343s
  user    0m0.400s
  sys     0m0.552s
  ```

In general, heredocs and herestrings are about the same speed (this is just one data set from several tests) while redirection is consistently more than 50% slower. Am I misunderstanding something, or could this be used as a general rule for commands reading standard input in Bash?

Comment: I'll certainly allow you a "useless use of `seq`" award ;-)

Comment: Note that you should either compare `cat <<END` vs. `cat <<< "test string"` vs. `echo "test string" | cat` or `cat <<'END'` vs. `cat <<< 'test string'` vs. `echo 'test string' | cat` to have the same amount of expansions performed by the shell on the strings.

Comment: @ChrisDown Derp. I always forget that one. Thanks!

Comment: @manatwork Thanks, fixed and updated timings.

Comment: Just a curiosity, what is with that reps? Wasn't your original intention to loop $reps times with `$(seq $reps)`?

Comment: @manatwork: Arg, you're right of course. Not really important, since it's just a test.

Comment: What is the purpose of `echo | cat` besides UUOC?

Comment: To clarify, you aren't actually measuring herestring / heredoc vs redirection, since the same redirection is present in all 3 examples (`> /dev/null`).  You are measuring single-process herestring / heredoc vs a 2-process pipe, and all that this exercise has demonstrated is that the pipe is slower, which is not a surprising result.

Comment: @jw013 It's simply an example. It's easy to think of a purpose for `echo | grep`, but using grep would have made the example look more specific.

Comment: @Random832 Replacing `cat` with `grep` doesn't change anything about what I said above.  Please reread my last comment, which doesn't actually mention `cat` at all.  The OP thinks he is comparing heredocs vs redirection, when he is actually comparing heredocs and *pipes*.

Comment: @jw013 I was responding to "What is the purpose of echo | cat besides UUOC?". I saw no indication that your later comment was meant to supersede that one.

Comment: @Random832 Indeed, the site doesn't allow comments to be edited after 5 minutes and I was too lazy to delete my original comment and repost.  The target of the "*To clarify*" bit in my 2nd comment was my first comment.

Comment: Personally I disagree with 'useless cat award'. My preference is to have consistent left-to-right flow of data. In `echo 'abc' | ...` the input is on LHS and output is on RHS. So is `cat 'abc' | ...` However `cmd1 < file | ...` and `(cmd1 <<<END ... END) | ...` have both ltr and rtl data flow. (As of speed - I don't use sh for performance but to hack a script in 5 s. For anything more complicated I'd use other languages - say Python).

Comment: @MaciejPiechotka `< file cmd1 | ...` - don't know if there's something similar for heredocs.

Comment: @MaciejPiechotka There are situations where right-to-left "flow" make sense, for example if you want to use the variables from a `while read` loop after the loop.

Comment: `<<EOF sed s/a/b/g ` works fine @Random832 :)  Even with pipes and continuations:  `<<EOF sed s/a/B/g | \ `  (newline) `sed s/c/D/g` — the input starts when the complete command is added.  (I tried this for the very first time now!)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First, let's concentrate on performance. I ran benchmarks for a slightly different program on an otherwise mostly idle x86_64 processor running Debian squeeze.

`herestring.bash`, using a herestring to pass a line of input:

```
#! /bin/bash
i=0
while [ $i -lt $1 ]; do
  tr a-z A-Z <<<'hello world'
  i=$((i+1))
done >/dev/null
```

`heredoc.bash`, using a heredoc to pass a line of input:

```
#! /bin/bash
i=0
while [ $i -lt $1 ]; do
  tr a-z A-Z <<'EOF'
hello world
EOF
  i=$((i+1))
done >/dev/null
```

`echo.bash`, using `echo` and a pipe to pass a line of input:

```
#! /bin/bash
i=0
while [ $i -lt $1 ]; do
  echo 'hello world' | tr a-z A-Z
  i=$((i+1))
done >/dev/null
```

For comparison, I also timed the scripts under ATT ksh93 and under dash (except for `herestring.bash`, because dash doesn't have herestrings).

Here are median-of-three times:

```
$ time bash ./herestring.bash 10000
./herestring.bash 10000  0.32s user 0.79s system 15% cpu 7.088 total
$ time ksh ./herestring.bash 10000
ksh ./herestring.bash 10000  0.54s user 0.41s system 17% cpu 5.277 total
$ time bash ./heredoc.bash 10000
./heredoc.bash 10000  0.35s user 0.75s system 17% cpu 6.406 total
$ time ksh ./heredoc.bash 10000  
ksh ./heredoc.sh 10000  0.54s user 0.44s system 19% cpu 4.925 total
$ time sh ./heredoc.bash 10000  
./heredoc.sh 10000  0.08s user 0.58s system 12% cpu 5.313 total
$ time bash ./echo.bash 10000
./echo.bash 10000  0.36s user 1.40s system 20% cpu 8.641 total
$ time ksh ./echo.bash 10000
ksh ./echo.sh 10000  0.47s user 1.51s system 28% cpu 6.918 total
$ time sh ./echo.sh 10000
./echo.sh 10000  0.07s user 1.00s system 16% cpu 6.463 total
```

Conclusions:

- A heredoc is faster than a herestring.
- `echo` and a pipe is noticeably, but not dramatically faster. (Keep in mind that this is a toy program: in a real program, most of the processing time would be in whatever the `tr` call stands for here.)
- If you want speed, ditch bash and call dash or even better ksh instead. Bash's features don't make up for its relative slowness, but ksh has both features and speed.

---

Beyond performance, there's also clarity and portability. `<<<` is a ksh93/bash/zsh extension which is less well-known than `echo … |` or `<<`. It doesn't work in ksh88/pdksh or in POSIX sh.

The only place where `<<<` is arguably significantly clearer is inside a heredoc:

```
foo=$(tr a-z A-Z <<<'hello world')
```

vs

```
foo=$(tr a-z A-Z <<'EOF'
hello world
EOF
)
```

(Most shells can't cope with closing the parenthesis at the end of the line containing `<<EOF`.)

Comment: Note that `<<<` comes from `rc`, and was first brought to the Bourne-like shell world by `zsh`. `rc` didn't add a trailing newline, but all of `bash`, `zsh` and `ksh93` do AFAICT. `rc` uses a pipe there, while `bash`, `zsh` and `ksh93` use a temporary file like for heredocs.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas Oops, I should have checked, thanks. This makes `<<<` even less useful.

Comment: Also note that `zsh` has an optimisation in `=(<<<foo)` to effectively create a temp file which contains "foo" which doesn't involve forking a process as `=(echo foo)` would.

Comment: I'll also mention that pdksh does *not* include `<<<`.

Comment: @kurtm “It doesn't work in ksh88/pdksh or in POSIX sh.”

Comment: @Gilles I had looked it up and wikipedia mentioned it worked "in ksh" (along with bash and zsh).  But I know pdksh has "some" ksh93 features.  So I tested it and figured I'd report.  I figured ksh88 was more explicitly not going to support it since you called out ksh93.

Answer (score 6):

Another reason to use heredocs (if you didn't have enough) is that echo can fail if the stream isn't consumed.  Consider having bash' `pipefail` option:

```
set -o pipefail
foo=yawn
echo $foo | /bin/true ; echo $?  # returns 0
```

`/bin/true` doesn't consume its standard input, but `echo yawn` completes nonetheless.  However, if echo is asked to print a lot of data, it will not complete until after `true` has completed:

```
foo=$(cat /etc/passwd)
# foo now has a fair amount of data

echo $foo | /bin/true ; echo $?  # returns 0 sometimes 141
echo $foo$foo$foo$foo | /bin/true ; echo $?  # returns mostly 141
```

141 is SIGPIPE (128 + 13) (128 being added because bash does so according to bash(1):

> When a command terminates on a fatal signal N, bash uses the value of 128+N as the exit status.

Heredocs don't have this problem:

```
/bin/true <<< $foo$foo$foo$foo ; echo $?  # returns 0 always
```

Comment: Thanks, this particular nuance was causing my script to fail intermittently at random places, more so on Amazon servers than on kvm hosts, but it still failed from time to time, in seemingly impossible-to-fail places.  It's a good thing that the `pipefail` defaults to being off!

Comment: Oh, I enable `pipefail` at the top of every script. Gimme all the errors!

Comment: @l0b0 Hmmm. Maybe I'll add pipefail to http://j.mp/safebash I'm all for getting all the errors during development!

Answer (score 4):

One reason you might want to use echo is to exhert some control the newline character that is added to the end of heredocs and herestrings:

Three characters `foo` has length 3:

```
$ echo -n foo | wc -c
3
```

However, a threecharacter herestring is four characters:

```
$ wc -c <<< foo
4
```

A three-character heredoc too:

```
$ wc -c << EOF
foo
EOF
4
```

The fourth character is a newline `0x0a` character.

Somehow this magically fits in with the way bash removes these newline characters when grabbing output from a sub-shell:

Here is a command that returns four characters: `foo` and `\n`. The '\n' is added by echo, it always adds a newline character unless you specify the `-n` option:

```
$ echo foo
foo
$ echo foo | wc -c
4
```

However, by assigning this to a variable, the trailing newline added by echo is removed:

```
$ foo=$(echo foo)
$ echo "$foo" # here, echo adds a newline too.
foo
```

So if you mix files and variables and use them in calculations (e.g. , you can't use heredocs or herestrings, since they will add a newline.

```
foo=abc
echo -n 'abc' > something.txt
if [ $(wc -c <<< "$foo") -eq $(wc -c < something.txt) ] ; then
  echo "yeah, they're the same!"
else
  echo "foo and bar have different lengths (except, maybe not)"
fi
```

If you change the if statement to read

```
if [ $(echo -n "$foo" | wc -c) -eq $(wc -c < something.txt) ] ; then
```

then the test passes.

Comment: Interesting. I made more precisely experiments and the behavior didn't go away. `foo="$(echo foo)"; echo -n "$foo" | wc -c` gives still 3.

Comment: For these one-liners with wc you can get around the \n registering as a character in the count with ```wc -L <<< foo```