# Bash function that accepts input from parameter or pipe

Tags: bash, pipe, function, stdin

I want to write the following bash function in a way that it can accept its input from either an argument or a pipe:

```
b64decode() {
    echo "$1" | base64 --decode; echo
}
```

Desired usage:

```
$ b64decode "QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQo="
$ b64decode < file.txt
$ b64decode <<< "QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQo="
$ echo "QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQo=" | b64decode
```

Comment: seems like a pointless function when `base64` and `bash` can do all that anyway.   why write a function just to avoid using the `-d` or `--decode` option?  if you really must have something called `b64decode` then `alias b64decode='base64 --decode'`.   `b64d` would be shorter, though and save even more typing.

Comment: You are right, this was just used as an example, though.

Comment: [Probably duplicate on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36432966/4970442)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

See [Stéphane Chazelas's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/607547) for a better solution.

---

You can use `/dev/stdin` to read from standard input

```
b64decode()
{
    if (( $# == 0 )) ; then
        base64 --decode < /dev/stdin
        echo
    else
        base64 --decode <<< "$1"
        echo
    fi
}
```

- `$# == 0` checks if number of command line arguments is zero
- `base64 --decode <<< "$1"` one can also use `herestring` instead of using `echo` and piping to `base64`

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain the advantage of `heredoc` here?

Comment: just a clean syntax imo, `echo and pipe` might be faster.. see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/59007/echo-vs-or-useless-use-of-echo-in-bash-award and it is `herestring`, I made a mistake

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with files containing multiple lines though.

Comment: does the `base64` command support multiple lines?

Comment: No, it appears it does not.

Comment: You could pipe the input through `tr -d "\n"` to remove lines breaks.

Comment: does base64 support multiple input lines?  of course it does, it would be pretty useless if it didn't.  see for yourself: `ls -l /usr/bin/  | base64 | base64 -d`

Comment: @cas, thanks.. I just tried by saving output of `ls -l /usr/bin/ | base64` to a file.. and then gave it as input to `b64decode`.. it works.. so not sure which case is failing for OP...

Comment: btw, +1.  yours is a good answer to a question that only makes any sense if it's just a standin for much more complicated function.

Comment: You don't actually need the `< /dev/stdin`; without a file, `base64` will simply read from the standard input it inherits from its parent, which is `/dev/stdin`.

Comment: @chepner, yes, and on Linux and Cygwin, using `< /dev/stdin` is even plain wrong, as it reopens the file currently open on stdin from scratch, so you end up not reading from stdin but from the start of the same file as open on stdin. It would also not work at all if stdin is a socket.

Answer (score 11):

Here it should just be:

```
b64decode() {
  if [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; then
    # concatenated arguments fed via a pipe.
    printf %s "$@" | base64 --decode
  else
    base64 --decode  # read from stdin
  fi
  ret=$?
  echo # add one newline character
  return "$ret" # return with base64's exit status to report decoding
                # errors if any.
}
```

In any case, do *not* use `base64 --decode < /dev/stdin`. At best (on most systems) `< /dev/stdin` does nothing, it just does the equivalent of `dup2(0,0)` (duplicating fd 0 onto fd 0, a no-op).

But on Linux or Cygwin, `< /dev/stdin` does not work properly here. On those systems, opening `/dev/stdin` is not like duplicating stdin, it reopens from scratch and independently the same file as is currently opened on stdin.

So if previously stdin was pointing in the middle of some regular file, after `< /dev/stdin`, you'll end up with stdin now pointing *at the start* of that file. If stdin was the writing end of a pipe (which it shouldn't under normal circumstances), you'll end up with it being the reading end. If it was a socket, then it will fail as sockets cannot be *opened*. Same if you don't have permission to open that file for reading (for instance because the permissions changed or the file was originally opened on stdin using different credentials).

And after `base64 --decode < /dev/stdin` returns, the current position of stdin within the file (for seekable file input) will have been left untouched, not left at the end (or wherever `base64` stopped reading) since `base64`'s stdin was on a different *open file description*.

Answer (score 6):

[Sundeep's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/301432/38638) works for `base64` because that utility does not support multiple lines. A more general fix for the more general case

- target utility allowing multiple commandline arguments
- [pipe or redirect containing multiple lines](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/301426/bash-function-that-accepts-input-from-parameter-or-pipe/301432#comment529116_301432)

is something like

```
my_function() {
    if (( ${#} == 0 )) ; then
        while read -r line ; do
            target_utility "${line}"
        done
    else
        target_utility "${@}"
    fi
}
```

Comment: (1) My version of `base64` supports multi-line input ([and so does cas’s](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/301426/23408#comment529275_301432)).  (2) In what sense is a utility that takes command-line arguments “the more general case” of a utility that reads standard input? If you want to answer a different question, you are free to post *that* question and answer it.  (3) You don’t need those curly braces, but you should quote `"$#"`.

Comment: @G-Man, you *should* quote `$#` in `[ "$#" -eq 0 ]`, you *may* quote it in `[[ $# -eq 0 ]]`, but you *must not* quote them in `if (( $# == 0 ))`. There's a missing `IFS=` before `read` though (and probably some `--`s depending on `target_utility`).

Comment: Also unclear why the answer is criticized for providing a "more general case" since the OP said "You are right, this [base64] was just used as an example, though. – tyrondis Aug 5 '16 at 22:45".

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: This is so confusing!  IMHO, it was a bad design decision to make quoting optional in ``[[``…``]]`` — it tells people that quoting isn’t so important, and so they try to memorize the rules for when quotes are required.  Forbidding quotes in `$((`…`))` is even worse.  As *[**you** said](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/80216#171347),* “one side effect of omitting quotes … is that it can send a wrong message to beginners: that it may be all right not to quote variables.” … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  And perhaps worse of all, the rules for `((`…`))` and ``$((``…``))`` are different — see [Shell Arithmetic Expansion with Quotes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/255196/80216).  I can get `if (( "$#" == 0 ))` to work; more to the point; I can’t get it to fail. Why do you say that I *must not* use quotes?

Comment: @G-Man, you must have bash 4.4 or newer where that changed. I can't see a difference between `((...))` and `$((...))`. Arithmetic expressions are evaluated as if inside double quotes in POSIX (word expansions performed, not tilde expansion, not globbing, no word splitting). In many shells (dash, zsh, bash4.3-, bosh) embedding a `'` or `"` will cause a syntax error as they're not arithmetic operators. Even `echo $(( 1 + ${0+"1"} ))` is a problem in bosh (OK in other shells). `(( 10 == 1"0" ))` is a problem in ksh93.

Comment: Hmmm, actually `$((...))` and `((...))` are indeed different in that regard *in mksh*.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: On the contrary, I’m using 4.1. … … … … For a specific example, I can say, `(("adams"="42"))`, `(("adams=42"))`, `(("adams"="17"+"25"))` or `(("adams"="17+25"))`, and I get `adams` set to `42`.  But of course `adams=$(("42"))` fails.

Comment: @G-Man, hmmm. Quick tests here seem to concur with you (though `a=$(("42"))` now works in 4.4+), I'll have to double check on the machine I ran tests the other day to understand what I did and why I said that.

Answer (score 6):

People are talking about how `base64 --decode` might really be
a placeholder for a more complicated command —
perhaps a pipeline or a compound command —
but nobody does anything about it (*). 
Well, here’s a non-recursive solution
in which the main commands appear only once:

```
b64decode() {
        if [ "$#" -ne 0 ]
        then
                printf '%s\n' "$1"
        else
                cat
        fi | base64 --decode
        echo
}
```

The logic is fairly simple:

- If there is an argument, write it to stdout.

  - (`printf` is safer than `echo`.)
  - The question doesn’t say what to do if there are two or more arguments,
    so I’m ignoring that case.
- If not, run a `cat`.

  - The lonesome cat isn’t useless. 
    UUOCs are typically characterized by having exactly one filename argument;
    this one has none. 
    It connects the input to the function
    (which is the input of the `if` statement)
    to the output of the `if` statement
    (which is the input to the `base64 –decode` statement),
    much like the `cat` in [this slightly similar answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/188217/80216).

But some people are allergic to cats, so here’s a feline-free version:

```
b64decode() {
    (
        if [ "$#" -ne 0 ]
        then
                exec <<< "$1"
        fi
        base64 --decode
        echo
    )
}
```

- This uses a here-string, so it works in bash,
  and I guess it will work in ksh (ksh93 or higher), mksh and zsh,
  but it won’t work in other POSIX-compliant shells.
- The logic is similar to the first version —
  if there is an argument, redirect stdin to a here-string of the argument,
  so `base64` will see it as stdin.
- Otherwise, do nothing (leave stdin alone).
- If the user says `b64decode < file.txt`,
  that (obviously) sets the stdin for the `b64decode`
  to be the `file.txt` file. 
  But, if we do any form of `exec <…`,
  that sets the stdin for the entire shell, globally. 
  So, after `base64` has read the here-string,
  the shell will get an end-of-file (EOF) and exit. 
  So, we run the entire function in a subshell. 
  Of course this means that the processing code
  cannot do anything that changes the shell’s environment.

_______________
(*) Except for kbulgrien, who [handled it with recursive code](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/593866/80216),
which strikes me as inappropriate.

Answer (score 3):

Both [Sundeep's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/109046/sundeep) and [TomRoche's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/38638/tomroche) answers were illuminating and appreciated, but in a different situation `target_utility "${@}"` could represent more complex code.  Duplicating non-trivial code in both the `if` and in the `else` could create unnecessary issues.  Though the OP's issue may not present a problem ideally resolved through use of recursion, other reader's problems may benefit from using it, or, from considering use of an wrapper function:

```
my_function() {
    if (( ${#} == 0 )) ; then
        while read -r __my_function ; do
            my_function "${__my_function}"
        done
    else
        target_utility "${@}"
    fi
}
```

This answer is one of various possible solutions for a "Bash function that accepts input from parameter or pipe" since the OP indicated [in a comment] that `base64` was not the actual problem domain.  As such, it makes no attempt to assure input is able to be directly read from a file.

Per various comments, there is concern this and similar other templates may not properly handle lines with leading white space; that `IFS =` may be required before the `read`.  In fact, presence of any character the shell is sensitive to may require special handling before it hits this function.  As-is, this code functions properly where leading white space is known to not occur, and where data sensitivities are pre-handled by the emitter.

This was not just a textbook example; it is used in an actual, production script.  `target_utility` is a simple moniker for the actual code fragment.  This answer does not presume to be a universal template without need for additional developer sagacity.

(It seems reasonable to assume users are often expected to occasionally adapt answers rather than expect to use them verbatim.)

Comment: (1) It seems unfortunate to use recursive code for a function that isn’t inherently recursive. (2) It seems unfortunate to use recursive code and not state in the text portion of your answer that you are using recursive code. (3) It seems unfortunate that you have followed TomRoche’s lead and written a loop, when the question does not appear to call for one.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the recursion and correcting the oversight. The answer credits others while solving a problem that wasn't optimally solved by other (helpful) answers at the time. I shared to help others. It is up to a reader to select answers and review for appropriateness to their needs. This almost looks like an attack when all that was required was an alternative answer standing on its own merits or demerits. Was "It is unfortunate" read it as an offensive statement to re-use in triplicate? I've edited it out; it was not intended as an attack as much as an observation.

Comment: (1) Yes, my wording was snarky and belligerent.  I apologize.  (2) I still have an issue with the (IMO, unsupported) interpretation that `b64decode` is supposed to invoke `target_utility` (`base64 --decode`) *with arguments*, and that `b64decode < file.txt` is supposed to read `file.txt` one line at a time and invoke `target_utility` *N* times.  (3) As @Stéphane Chazelas pointed out in a comment on TomRoche’s answer, `read` should be `IFS= read` (to support input lines that begin with space or tab).  (4) Thank you for cleaning up Mohsen Banan’s answer.

Comment: The title of the question is what triggered the process of finding this Q/A for material that aided development of the above to solve a real life problem described by the title.  The OP declared that base64 decode was not the "real" problem; pedantic constraint of answers to a particular "example" seems less helpful.  When this question and its answers were key to helping solve real problems, alternate answers can be gifts to the community in recognition of the fact that many more people will use this Q/A to solve problems.  Since the answer is on-topic per the title, I feel it is "game on".

Comment: More boiler-plate added to the answer, but the value of what really seems to be nitpicking seems questionable even if there is also value in a judicious hunt for theoretical ideals. In the end, this site is about helping community. All the associated answers and comments are available for a visitor to peruse and consider. It is decidedly less valuable to the community when all answers are identical. If one had to deal with the drain of such critique for every answer, perhaps site usage would go down. People have lives to lead and the OP is apparently already happy. IMO, it is time to move on.

Answer (score -5):

Here is an example in the BSIP dialect of bash.

```
function vis_userAcctsReport {
G_funcEntry
function describeF {  G_funcEntryShow; cat  << _EOF_
Report on a user account, inputs can come from args or from stdin
Examples:
      ${G_myName} -i userAcctsReport bisos
      echo bisos bystar | ${G_myName} -i userAcctsReport
_EOF_
}
local inputsList="$@"
local thisFunc=${G_thisFunc}

function processEach {
EH_assert [[ $# -eq 1 ]]
local userAcctName=$1
if ! vis_userAcctsExist ${userAcctName} ; then
    EH_problem "${userAcctName} Does Not Exist -- ${thisFunc} Processing Skipped"
    lpReturn 101
fi

ANT_raw "--- ${userAcctName}: passwd, group, id, sudoers ---"

lpDo getent passwd ${userAcctName}
lpDo getent group ${userAcctName}

lpDo sudo -u ${userAcctName} id
lpDo sudo grep ${userAcctName} /etc/sudoers
}

if [ $# -gt 0 ] ; then
local each=""
for each in ${inputsList} ; do
    lpDo processEach ${each}
done
else
local eachLine=""
while read -r -t 1 eachLine ; do
    if [ ! -z "${eachLine}" ] ; then
    local each=""
    for each in ${eachLine} ; do
        lpDo processEach ${each}
    done
    fi
done
fi

lpReturn
}
```

Disclosure:  This answer relates to "BSIF (ByStar Shell-based/bash-based Integration Facilities) Namespace: A name base for a collection of bash libraries and bash commands for autonomous services intgration [sic]."  The answering party is the author/maintainer of the `bsip` package as represented at https://pypi.org/project/bsif/

Comment: What does "BSIP" mean?

Comment: There are several un-defined commands in your function; hopefully there's a "BSIP" library of some kind that defines them?

Comment: (1) No indication of what BSIP is. (Google doesn’t know what it is, and neither does Jeff.) (2) *A **lot*** of code to handle a fairly simple problem, with no explanation. (3) It’s not clear that this even answers the question. At best, it might be a wrong answer.

Comment: It is a long-standing grammar rule that suggests acronyms not be used without first elaborating what they stand for.  Refusal to expand one on a well-meaning query seems... well... difficult.

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/bsif "BSIF (ByStar Shell-based/bash-based Integration Facilities) Namespace: A name base for a collection of bash libraries and bash commands for autonomous services intgration [sic]. Support For support, ideas, suggestions, criticism, comments and questions; please contact the author/maintainer Mohsen Banan at: " <redacted /> ... "Installation pip install bsip"